# Show arguments while debugging

Tags: ida, debugging, arguments

I am a developer but I do not have much experience with IDA/reverse-engineering. Now I have to analyse a compiled program.
Currently I try to debug a simple wininet.dll:wininet_InternetReadFile-function and I wonder: where can I see the concrete arguments for this function while debugging?

Currently I am at this point:

[image]

I am pretty sure you can (almost) see the arguments (or at least its address) in this screenshot. But I am a beginner in reverse engineering. I don't get it/don't see it.

What is the easiest/best way to get the URL that should be downloaded in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Since eax,ebx etc are used instead of rax,rbx etc in your screen shot
i assume it is some x86 code and not x64 code

since there doesnt appear a push {} for arguments prior to the call
i assume this code is not compiled with msvc

it appears to use a mov arguments to stack kind  which ida doesnt seem to decode
(ida should usually show the hFile,etc args if it was standard vs compiled exe

(screenshot shows the disassembly of src code compiled from [here](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/downloading-a-web-page-in-c-using-wininet.html) using vs2017 15.8.1 x86 32bit

[image]

the prototype for this [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetreadfile) is

```
BOOLAPI InternetReadFile(
  HINTERNET hFile,
  LPVOID    lpBuffer,
  DWORD     dwNumberOfBytesToRead,
  LPDWORD   lpdwNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

in your screenshot var 47c,478,474,470 are the arguments to this specific function

take a look at VIEW ESP window in your screen shot
cc0xxx is your  **HINTERNET hFile** argument
var 454 is your **LPVOID lpBuffer**
0x3E8 is the    **DWORD     dwNumberOfBytesToRead**,
var_458 is the pointer to recieve the number of bytes read  **LPDWORD   lpdwNumberOfBytesRead**